# Get latest Rekonq developmental source code

Tags: compiling, kde, browser, development

I see that I can get the latest stable Rekonq through http://sourceforge.net/projects/rekonq/, but I want to get the latest developmental-version/daily-build. Where can I obtain the developmental source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you can get it here:

```
$ git clone git://anongit.kde.org/rekonq
```

Page on installing and compiling it is here:

- https://techbase.kde.org/Projects/rekonq/Compiling_rekonq